# Apps Script issue with copy and paste data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get my google sheet form to transfer data from qualityForm to dailyData. It's transferring it but what I'm running into is that when it transfers it's not pushing the older data down on the dailyData tab so that the new data can stack on top or clearing the existing info after the submit button is clicked on qualityForm. Also, if there's a way to transfer straight from the form instead of making cells H2:K7 equal to the data I'm trying to move. I've only ever done this with macro's so this was how I had to do it.

Here is the code I have:

```
function copypaste(sourcelink,sourcesheet,sourcerange,destilink,destisheet,destirange) {
  
  //Source link
  var ssraw = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sourcelink);
  var sheetraw = ssraw.getSheetByName(sourcesheet);
  var range = sheetraw.getRange(sourcerange);
  var data = range.getValues();
  
  //Destination
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(destilink);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(destisheet);
  
  //transfer to destination range
  sheet.getRange(destirange).clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(destirange).setValues(data);
}

function run() {
  copypaste("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yfE_WYGiRpgxYl29cUN6Vww3V9FjCf1FeprSyckQnms/edit#gid=0","qualityForm","H2:K7",
            "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yfE_WYGiRpgxYl29cUN6Vww3V9FjCf1FeprSyckQnms/edit#gid=1308466616","dailyData","A2:D7") }
```

Comment: Here is the link

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yfE_WYGiRpgxYl29cUN6Vww3V9FjCf1FeprSyckQnms/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent) and [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues), you're erasing the values from that range and then writing only the new data, so the existing data is lost.

To keep the existing data and insert new rows at the beginning of the sheet, you could [insert a few rows](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowsrowindex) and write the new data to it, but probably a faster approach is to read the current data and append it to the end of the array holding the new data, writing everything after that:

```
function copypaste(sourcelink,sourcesheet,sourcerange,destilink,destisheet,destirange) {
  //Source link
  var ssraw = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sourcelink);
  var sheetraw = ssraw.getSheetByName(sourcesheet);
  var range = sheetraw.getRange(sourcerange);
  var data = range.getValues();
  
  //Destination
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(destilink);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(destisheet);
  
  var currentContent = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var newContent = data.concat(currentContent);

  //transfer to destination range
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, newContent.length, newContent[0].length).setValues(newContent);
}
```

By the way, if you're only working with the spreadsheet your script is [bound to](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound), it might be a good idea to take a look at [getActiveSpreadsheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivespreadsheet) instead of passing links and opening them with [openByUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl).

> if there's a way to transfer straight from the form instead of making cells H2:K7 equal to the data I'm trying to move.

Yes, you can do that by using the values in the form to create an array in the same format as the range *H2:K7*:

```
function submitForm() {
  //Source link
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('qualityForm');
  var destinationSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('dailyData');
  
  // Get form data
  var date = sourceSheet.getRange('B4').getValue();
  var name = sourceSheet.getRange('E4').getValue();
  var items = sourceSheet.getRange('B8:E13').getValues();
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    data.push([date, name, items[i][0], items[i][3]]);
  }

  // Get current content
  var currentContent = destinationSheet.getRange(2, 1, destinationSheet.getLastRow()-1, destinationSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var newContent = data.concat(currentContent);

  //transfer to destination range
  destinationSheet.getRange(2, 1, newContent.length, newContent[0].length).setValues(newContent);
}
```

Comment: I tried editing like suggested and using getActiveSpreadsheet and got error message. "Exception: The parameters (null) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getUrl. (line 4, file "Code")

Comment: I don't know what changes you made to your code, so I cannot tell what is causing that error. In any case, I've updated the second snippet in my answer to show how to use getActiveSpreadsheet().

Comment: Chances are they are using a [standalone script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone). I edited that in the answer in order to clarify this.

Comment: It could be, but the sample spreadsheet in the question's comment has a bound script. In any case, that's an important detail. Thanks for adding it.

Comment: I made the suggested changes shown in the second snippet but I'm still getting error message. `Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1. (line 17, file "Code")

Comment: Figured that part out. It was because there needed to be data already in the rows and I had deleted it in the dailyData tab. It's still not clearing out the information on the qualityForm though after submission.

Comment: Figured that out too. Went in and add .clearContent at the bottom the range values.